# Getting percent sign to show up in pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

So this is probably a very basic question but I can't find an answer to it anywhere.

I'm trying to create some pie charts and I've managed to get them looking how I want to for the most part but when it comes to getting the percent sign to show up inside the pie slices themselves I just can't get it to work.

As I understand it, including `autopct='%.1f%%'` in `plt.pie()` should do exactly what I want but it just doesn't work no matter what I do. I've tried copying other people's code and seeing if it works with that but nope; all I'm getting is "30" inside the pie slices instead of "30%."

I'm hoping it's just a simple fix but nothing I've tried is working so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: This is the exact code as it stands:

```py
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)

mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

plt.style.use('seaborn')

rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

values = [7, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1]
labels = ["18–24", "25–34", "35–44", "45–54", "55–64", "$>$65"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))


plt.pie(values, autopct='%.1f%%',
        wedgeprops={"linewidth" : 2.0, "edgecolor": "white"},
        textprops={'size': 'xx-large'})

plt.tight_layout()

plt.legend(labels=labels, loc='best')

plt.show()
```

And this is what I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: `autopct='%.1f%%` That is clearly missing a closing quote mark, so it can't be the real code you tried.  Please show us the real code.

Comment: I just edited the question and added all of what I've written.

Comment: If I comment out the two `usetex` lines, your pie chart is correct.  It's something related to TeX.  Do you need to escape the %?  I'm not sure.

Comment: @Tim Yeah that made it work now, definitely TeX related. I'll have to find a work around then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success with escaping the second '%':

```
...,autopct='%.1f\%%',...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need the answer, but maybe someone else does.

The reason your code doesn't display the % sign is because you set up a custom font. If you remove the font or try to find a font that is compatible with the pie chart, the % sign will appear.

This is the only reason.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the font that was messing with it or the `usetex=True` because the solution seems to have been to escape the percent sign which worked despite me keeping the custom font. Nonetheless, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this little block:

```
plt.pie([30, 25], autopct='%.1f%%')
```

And it gave me this:

[image]

So I don't think your issue is in the `plt.pie()` or `autopct='%.1f%%'`